# How should I diagnose randomly repeated HTTP requests to an application?

Tags: virtual-machines, http, haproxy

I'm running a service which is a third party commercial web application behind haproxy load balancers. A while ago, I started seeing http requests being repeated, like a stutter - the same request would be rapidly repeated many times until the application fell over (as its session mechanism couldn't cope) or denial of service attack detection kicked in and blocked the IP. Both webserver and load balancer are on virtual machines; the load balancers run on a failover clustered pair of redhat 6 machines while the backends are two redhat 6 machines.

The repeats seem to always be for functions rather than files, and are not usually the first request from an IP address in a session.

I've looked at a number of possibilities and pretty much ruled them out:

It doesn't appear to be malicious, as we have received these repeated requests from locations both on internal network and external IPs (but not from the local subnet). Behaviour earlier in the session from the same IP is generally like normal traffic - and the likelihood that we are blocking legitimate traffic with the denial of service attack detection is why I think it is important to sort this out.

It doesn't seem to be buggy versions of browsers. Although I've found by Googling that this can happen with old versions of Safari, and these are the main culprits, other browsers are also showing up in the log files with repeated requests.

It's probably not the load balancers, as the repeated requests appear in the haproxy logs. (I'm not absolutely certain about this, as I don't know precisely when in the load balancing process a log line is generated).

It's not the virtual infrastructure, as we recently migrated the service from one virtual infrastructure to another, and the issue continued just the same.

The third party application is basically a search tool, and handles thousands of searches a day. Many of the repeated requests are search requests, but they are a very small percentage (about one per day) of the essentially identical requests made without error. It's also not an issue which has been raised by the customer mailing list we're on, and we have mentioned it to the vendor but thy don't think it's a fault of their application.

I could provide log lines if people want to see them, but I don't think there's anything distinctive about the requests involved, so I think this is unlikely to help.

Any suggestions of causes or ways to diagnose what's happening much appreciated!

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: From your description you have more or less concluded that the problem is not in your infrastructure and logically the issue is most probably the web application. Log a support request with the vendor and get them to investigate, often a developer will quite easily narrow which part of his code triggers the web requests you're logging and can work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the sensible comment - I've added more information about the application which should show why I don't think that's the cause.